# Organizing jbuttons in flowLayout java

Tags: java, layout

I am struggling how to make a good looking layout.

I am trying to add one button to left side and 2 buttons to right side.
I tried many ways to get this good looking, therefore, doesn't work well. Any help would be great.

```
JPanel btn1 = new JPanel();
btn1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
btn1.add(new JButton("btn1"));
JButton btn2 = new JButton("btn2");
btn1.add(btn2);
pane.add(btn1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Since I am not allow to post the image:

```
-----------------------------------------
| ------------------------------------- |
| |                                   | |
| |                                   | |
| |                                   | |
| |                                   | |
| ------------------------------------- |
| [ enter ]                [btn1][btn2] |
-----------------------------------------
```

How would I make the enter button to left side.

Thanks.

Attempt 3:

```
JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    JPanel enter = new JPanel();
    JPanel btn1_btn2 = new JPanel();

    enter.add(new JButton("Enter"));
    enter.setLayout((new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING)));
    southPanel.add(enter);


    btn1_btn2.add(new JButton("btn1"));
    btn1_btn2.add(new JButton("btn2"));
    btn1_btn2.setLayout((new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING)));

    southPanel.add(btn1_btn2);
```

Comment: you have many options to consider, one of them is to put [enter], [btn1] and [btn2] into a panel with grid layout, cell1 has [enter] cell2 empty cell3 empty cell 4 has panel that contains [btn1] and [btn2]

Comment: If you don't mind using a different layout, you should check out GridLayout or GridBagLayout. I prefer GridBagLayout due to its flexability. Let me know if you want an example

Comment: @VinceEmigh It would be great if you can provide an example. I am new to the design and willing to play around.

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly I don't quite understand you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could nest panels with different FlowLayout orientations (LEADING, TRAILING)

[image]

Comment: I am still having trouble creating it. Please take a look at Attempt 2: in my post.

Comment: No, what you want to do, for the south panel, is set the layout the `GridLayout(1, 2)`. Then you need to add two panels to that panel. The left with FlowLayout.LEADING, and the right to FlowLayout.TRAILING. The left panel, you add the enter button. The right panel, you add the other two buttons.

Comment: Thank you it works. Check Attempt 3 in my post please. I have one question, I don't get how btn1 and btn2 works with event listener since the variable name are the same. How would I interact with btn1 and btn2? you know what I mean? like btn1 means start timer, or btn2 means stop timer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a panel using a BorderLayout.
2. Add the "Enter" button to the WEST.
3. Create a second panel and add the other two buttons to the panel. Then add that panel to the EAST of the panel using the BorderLayout
4. Add the panel with the BorderLayout to your frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example you asked for:

Although GridBagLayout can be pretty complex, it is extremely flexible. It's really not that hard either, once you get familiar with your options (weight, anchor, ipadx, ect..)

I highly suggest you reading up on GridBagLayout and learn the features that come along with it.
Unlike other layouts, GridBagLayout depends on another object (call the constraints) to set attributes to your components. All components typically share the same GridBagConstraints to avoid unnecessary object accolation

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App {

    private static JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initFrame();
    }

    private static void initFrame() {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() { //all swing actions should be handled on EDT
                public void run() {
                    frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setSize(500, 500);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //close process on X

                    addComponents(frame.getContentPane()); //add components to frame

                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //set frame in center of screen
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void addComponents(Container pane) {
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JButton button = new JButton("button1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("b2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("b3");

        //we are anchroing our button to the bottom-left side of the screen
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;

        //weightx and y specifiy that our comp isn't just mindlessly floating around
        //for weightx, if there is any extra space on the X axis, fill ass needed
        //same for weighty. if we didnt have these vars, our comp will float in the middle
        //basically, if you dont have these, your "anchor" wont be noticed
        gbc.weighty = .5;
        gbc.weightx = .5; 
        pane.add(button, gbc);

        //since we are now working with the other 2 buttons, make it south east
        //we must change our weightx back to 0, to ensure there will be no spacing between
        //our two buttons (even if there is extra space, dont use it)
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        pane.add(button2, gbc);
        pane.add(button3, gbc);
    }
}
```